# What are the service running for mssql server on linux, and how to check if they are running

Tags: linux, sql-server, systemctl

On microsoft's site I can see the mssql-server on linux has following components

1. Mssql server (database engine)
2. SSIS (integration services)
3. full text service
4. High Availability

I can only see if database engine is running or not using

`systemctl status mssql-server`

How can I know if other services are running or not. Or is there only mssql-server service in linux which can be turned on and off?

P.S: I can see status of 'SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (MSSQL)' and SQL 'Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)' using

`select * from sys.dm_server_services`

Is there a way i.e. using `systemctl` command get datails of all these services?

Answer (score 0):

You need install your FTS

sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server-fts

Lern more here: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017